# Print stars based on a number in each span

Tags: jquery, replace, append

I have some spans with the same class. And there's a number in each span, generated by PHP. I need the number in every element to be changed to the same number of stars.

So if the number is 4, there'll be 4 stars (*).

My actual code:

```
$(function(){
   var number = $("parent-div").find("span").text();

   for (var i = 1; i < number; i++){
    $("span").append("*");
}
});
```

Well, it doesn't work for me :/ . I also tried functions like .replaceWith() and .text() instead of append().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the period in the class selector, and to just replace the number with stars I would do something like this

```
$(".parent-div span").text(function (_, txt) {
    return (new Array(parseInt(txt, 10) + 1)).join('*');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/43FRg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("parentdiv").find("span").each(function () {
       var number = $(this).text();
       $(this).text("");
       for (var i = 1; i < parseInt(number); i++) {
           $(this).append("*");
       }
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8jHpq/